# Where to start repairing furnace that clicks when running?

Tags: hvac

My furnace makes a clicking sound when the heat is on. The heat works well though, and If I turn only the fan on there is no clicking.

When the heat turns on, the clicking starts out slower and after about a minute it gets much faster and louder.

I have pinpointed the sound to this part:
[image: noisy]

I’m not sure if it’s the small black wheel or the part it spins further back. What is this part called? I would like to at least have some idea what the cost of the part is before calling anyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the inducer motor.

If it's making a clicking sound, that could mean that the bearings are bad, and/or that there's something physically coming into contact with the spinning bits of the inducer.

Answer (score 0):

that part is called the "inducer" motor. It's job is to help "push" out the exhaust gases caused by combustion. when a bearing starts to go bad you might here a "squealing" Noise. With the furnace off, spin the black "wheel" by hand. It should spin smooth with no noise. it should spin freely. if it stops, squeals, or just doesn't feel right, then it should be replaced.

Comment: Your answer is the same as testers on a 3yr old question, make sure you have additional information or now it is pulled up again since the op did not up vote to show the question was answered. And we waste time reading everything again.